# SASS Escape Calc for SquareSpace

Tags: css, sass

How can I stop SASS from interpreting `calc(90vh - 1.5em)` to instead compile as is?

Currently, the SASS compiles to `calc(88.5vh)`.

I have attempted `#{'calc(90vh - 1.5em)'}` and `calc(#{'90vh'} - #{'1.5em'})` with no success.

---

**UPDATE**

SASS is not the issue. Compiled CSS is being uploaded to SquareSpace where it is compiled yet again. The initial compiled CSS via SASS is correct.

---

**SOLVED**

To resolve I needed to escape both the SASS and the SquareSpace LESS compilers.

`#{'~"calc(90vh - 1.5em)"'}`

Comment: Have you tried `calc(90vh - #{1.5em})`

Comment: @dw_ Same result.

Comment: @dw_ I've just realized it's not SASS, it's SquareSpace further compiling the code.

Comment: How about `unquote("calc(90vh - 1.5em)");`

Comment: Yeah, I was curious as to why this is happening - as I've tested it locally and most of the options you provided work.

Comment: @dw_ Thank you for the help.

Comment: @RyanPrentiss You should post your solution as an answer (and then accept it) instead of adding it to your question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve I needed to escape both the SASS and the SquareSpace LESS compilers.

`#{'~"calc(90vh - 1.5em)"'}`